# Angular-filter omit with dynamic element from scope

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters

JS:

    `var MyApp = angular.module('SOFdemo',['angular.filter']);
    MyApp.controller('SOFCtrl',['$scope','$resource','$location',function($scope,$resource,$location){
    $scope.serverSizeOptions = [
    {"name":"20 Users","value":20},
    {"name":"30 Users","value":30},
    {"name":"40 Users","value":40},
    {"name":"50 Users","value":50},
    {"name":"60 Users","value":60},
    {"name":"70 Users","value":70},
    {"name":"80 Users","value":80},
    {"name":"90 Users","value":90}];
}]);`

I want to display on a table the possible options for a customer that subscribe to a max and min size. I'm using the directive angular-filter

I assigned the controller to my body.

The following ng-repeat directive usage on my partial HTML working well for a tr:

`< tr ng-repeat="(key,value) in (serverSizeOptions | omit: value<20 | omit: value>50)">
    < td>{{key}}
    < td>{{value}}
    < /tr>`

Now, I would like to change 20 or 50 by my project size like:

```
< tr ng-repeat="(key,value) in (serverSizeOptions | omit: value<20 | omit: value> project.size.value)"> ...
```

But here, filter is not applied and I have all my list. 
project.size.value is on my current scope.
I tried several configuration since hours and I'm starting to think that it's not possible to do what I'm expecting.

Any help will be appreciate.

Comment: there is not enough code here to reproduce your issue to identify what the issue is.

Comment: I tried to add some code Claies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the filterFilter and define a function on your scope, that selects the valid values.

ng-repeat = "item in serverSizeOptions | filter:myFunction"

$scope.myFunction = function(item) { ..your logic here return a boolean }

Comment: I thought that the angular-filter could avoid me to create specific filter functions each time that I need to create a list of something. :(

Comment: I implemented this on my project and I get what I want. Thanks